# Setting boundaries for pinch-zoom in Maps view

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, pinchzoom

For an app I'm working on the user needs to be able to zoom in and out using pinch gestures, but only within a certain boundary.

There are multiple "levels" on which users can see the map and there should be a settable zoom boundary for each of these.

We got this working partially by resetting the camera back to the limit if pinching has brought it outside of it's boundaries, but the user shouldn't be able to pinch out/in of the boundaries at all.

Here's a video of how it's working now:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WfAle_M-i0k

And how it should work is that once the camera is at the zoomlevel-limit, zooming out further shouldn't be possible.

This is important because we'll be drawing a lot of objects on the screen and the app crashes when it's zoomed out too far.

We're using the default pinch-zoom that comes with

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
```

Is there a way to disable further zooming in/out when the boundary has been reached?

Comment: No, it's the right video.

Comment: It's the regular Google Maps API map. Do you see a video at all? It works fine here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any other way of doing this that implementing zoom controls by yourself, i.e. setting

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
```

and adding buttons on top of your map with actions with [zoomBy](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory.html#zoomBy(float)) inside (with respect to your zoom boundaries kept somewhere).

You may also check [lite mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lite).

Comment: I apologise for the late reply. Unfortunately we can't use buttons for this as we already have quite a stuffed GUI (which is not visible yet in the video above) so we really need to use pinch controls for this.

Comment: Lite mode disables gestures completely and seeing as the performance issues are with our drawn polygons and not with Google Maps in general, I don't see how Lite mode would help with our problem.